# How do do you edit HTML form elements’ in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I’m trying to make a simple font generator for a challenge. The form element I’m trying to edit is the  tag.

The way this webpage is supposed to work is a user types in the “input textbox”, presses one of the 3 buttons and the new text will appear in the “output textbox” in the font that the user chooses.

This is what my HTML looks like:

```
<div id=“inputContainer”>
    <p id=“inputText style=“text-decoration:underline;position:relative;”>Input</p>
    <textarea id=“input” rows=“10” columns=“10”></textarea>
</div>
<div id=“outputContainer”>
    <p id=“outputText” style=“text-decoration:underline;position:relative;”>Output</p>
    <textarea id=“output” rows=“10” columns=10”></textarea>
</div>
```

And here is my jQuery/JS:

```
var inputText = $("#input").html();
    $("#monospaceButton").click(function() {
    $("#output").html(inputText);
});
```

The function only works if I manually add text between the  tags (innerHTML). When the user types in the textarea in the code’s output (The website.), there will be no output in the “output” textarea.

I appreciate any help. Please let me know if I need to explain anything more clearly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$("#button1").click(function() {
                var value = $("#input").val();
                $("#output").css('font-family', 'serif');
                $("#output").val(value);
            });
            $("#button2").click(function() {
                var value = $("#input").val();
                $("#output").css('font-family', 'monospace');
                $("#output").val(value);
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
            <p id="inputText" style="text-decoration:underline;position:relative;">Input</p>
            <textarea id="input" rows="3" columns="10"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button id="button1">Style 1</button>
        <button id="button2">Style 2</button>
        <div>
            <p id="outputText" style="text-decoration:underline;position:relative;">Output</p>
            <textarea id="output" rows="3" columns="10"></textarea>
        </div>
```